# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'. C# Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

There seems to be a problem in my code here it is:

**C#**

```
        protected void ddlCalltype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          if (ddlCalltype.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
          DataSet dsFormat = new DataSet();

         String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

         using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
          {
           con.Open();

           using (cmd = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
             {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               da.SelectCommand = cmd;
               da.Fill(dsFormat);
             }
               con.Close();
       }
       ddlFormat.DataValueField = "DISPFORMAT";
       ddlFormat.DataTextField = "FORMATDETAIL";
       ddlFormat.DataSource = dsFormat.Tables[0];
       ddlFormat.DataBind();
       ddlFormat.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");

       using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
       {
           con.Open();
           DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
           SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
           using (cmd1 = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
           {
               cmd1.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0";
               cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd1.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd1.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
               da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
               da1.Fill(ds1);

               dt = ds1.Tables[0];
               gvDetails.DataSource = ds1;
               gvDetails.DataBind();

           }
           con.Close();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       ddlFormat.Items.Clear();
   }
 }
```

Hello Everyone..I know this question have been asked again and again..but I'm unable to get my answer from the answers please suggest me anything..what mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried it without the nested using?

Comment: Shouldn't that be da1.SelectCommand = cmd1; instead of da.SelectCommand = cmd1; ?

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder no i have nt tried

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel thanks i noticed it now.. but now another error is coming

Comment: after correcting it this error is coming.... ERROR: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: Can you add your stored procedure? The one that's called 'ROMA_UserManagement'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have assigned the select command to wrong `SqlDataAdapter` instance in this part:

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
da1.Fill(ds1);
```

This makes `da1` instance left open without any select command applied to it, hence throwing exception. Correct assignment should be `da1.SelectCommand = cmd1;`.

The second problem `Cannot find table 0` thrown when executed query contains empty results, hence either `dsFormat.Tables[0]` or `ds1.Tables[0]` becomes empty and can't be assigned to data binding.

To check if the query producing results, use if-condition to check table count like this example:

```
if (ds1.Tables.Count > 0 && ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // grid data binding here
}
```

By combining these solutions, database connection should be composed as shown below:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (cmd = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dsFormat);
    }
    con.Close();
}

if (dsFormat.Tables.Count > 0 && dsFormat.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ddlFormat.DataValueField = "DISPFORMAT";
    ddlFormat.DataTextField = "FORMATDETAIL";
    ddlFormat.DataSource = dsFormat.Tables[0];
    ddlFormat.DataBind();
    ddlFormat.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");
}

using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (cmd1 = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0";
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
        da1.Fill(ds1);

        if (ds1.Tables.Count > 0 && ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             dt = ds1.Tables[0];
             gvDetails.DataSource = ds1; // are you mean to assign dt here?
             gvDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

By performing check to examine empty results in `DataSet`/`DataTable` before applying data binding to a control, exceptions can be avoided thereafter.

**Edit:**

According to OP's comment, the given stored procedure requires output parameter which can implemented as this:

```
// change SqlDbType.Varchar to other data type required for output parameter (Int, DateTime, etc.)
var output = new SqlParameter("@outputparamname", SqlDbType.Varchar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

// change or also apply to `cmd` depending which `SqlCommand` requires output parameter
cmd1.Parameters.Add(output);
```

Comment: i tried your code and now error is not coming..but on the same side it also not showing output

Comment: Is the query returning empty results in `DropDownList`/`GridView`? Check the stored procedure named `ROMA_UserManagement` in SSMS, is it working properly when assigned to value from C# code then? Use debugger to see `dsFormat.Tables.Count` and `ds1.Tables.Count` value, if both of them returns 0 hence something wrong happened.

Comment: yes you are right ...actually it is working but its displaying nothing because i have nt supplied output parameter..

Comment: I added implementation of output parameter required by stored procedure in `SqlCommand`, try to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to initialize Sqldata adapter after command object

This is only single example

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          SqlDataAdapter da=null;
          DataSet dsFormat = new DataSet();

         String strConnString = 

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

         using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
          {
           con.Open();

           using (cmd = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
             {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value ="";
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               da.Fill(dsFormat);
             }
               con.Close();
       }
       ddlFormat.DataValueField = "DISPFORMAT";
       ddlFormat.DataTextField = "FORMATDETAIL";
       ddlFormat.DataSource = dsFormat.Tables[0];
       ddlFormat.DataBind();
       ddlFormat.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");
```